# Django giving "IntegrityError NOTNULL constraint failed" when submitting django form data

Tags: django, forms

I'm making a simple webapp in django where a user can log in , choose one of the given category and post an article under the chosen category. But when I submit my django form to create a new post, it throws me " IntegrityError NOTNULL constraint failed ". I searched many solutions on internet and implemented the same but still it gives me the same error.

Please help me out as to how I fix this bug??

Here are the code snippets:

Models.py

```
class  Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)    


    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def index(request):

    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'category_list':category_list}

    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def category(request,category_name_slug):

    context = {}
    try:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_name_slug)
        context['category_name'] = category.name

        post = Post.objects.filter(category=category)   
        context['post'] = post
        context['category'] = category
        context['category_name_slug'] = category_name_slug
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request,'category.html',context)

@login_required     
def create_post(request,category_name_slug):

    created = False
    instance = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_name_slug)
    a = Post(category=instance)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST,instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            created = True
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context={
        'form':form,
        'instance':instance,        
        'created':created
    }
    return render(request,"add_post.html",context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from app.models import Post,Category,UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter category")
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','content')

        exclude = ('category',)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
        url(r'^about/$',views.about,name='about'),
        url(r'^add_category/$',views.add_category,name="add_category"),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[-\w]+)/create_post/$',views.create_post, name='create_post'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.category, name='category'),
        url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.post_detail,name='post'),
        url(r'^register/$',views.register,name="register"),
        url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name="login"),
        url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name="logout"),
        url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$',views.view_profile,name="profile"),
```

]

templates/add_post.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Post</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"                   integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create Post under {{ instance.name }}</h1>
        {% if created %}
            <strong>Post created successfully</strong>
            <a href='/app/'>Home</a>
        {% else %}
        <form id='post_form' method='post' action='/app/category/{{ instance.slug }}/create_post/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post" />
        </form>
        {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

templates/category.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"                   integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% if category %}
        <h1>{{ category_name }}</h1>
            {% if post %}
            <ul>
                {% for poste in post %}
                    <li>{{ poste.title }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% else %}
                <strong>No posts in this Category</strong>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <strong>No Category found with {{ category_name }}</strong>
        {% endif %}
        <a href='/app/category/{{ category.slug }}/create_post/'>Create post</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

It's shows me an error at " post.save() " line in views.py.

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace and the template that is rendering the form.

Comment: Would like to see your PostForm